# Plancherel theorem for multi-dimensional discrete Fourier transform

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

If $k\in\mathbb N$, then the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) of $x\in\mathbb C^k$ can be defined as $$\hat x_\omega:=\frac1k\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}e^{-{\rm i}2\pi\omega\frac ik}x_i\;\;\;\text{for }\omega\in\{0,\ldots,k-1\}$$ (I'm slightly abusing notation by starting indexiation of a $k$-dimensional vector at $0$).

Now, the Plancherel therorem can be written as $$\|x\|=\|\hat x\|,\tag1$$ where $\|\;\cdot\;\|$ is the usual norm on $\mathbb C^k$.

---

Now I wonder how $(1)$ can generalized to the multi-dimensional DFT. Let $x\in\mathbb C^{k_1\times\cdots\times k_d}$ and (using vector notation) $$\hat x_\omega:=\frac1k\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}e^{-{\rm i}2\pi\left\langle\omega,\:\frac ik\right\rangle}x_i$$ for $\omega\in\{0,\ldots,k_1-1\}\times\cdots\times\{0,\ldots,k_d-1\}$. Does $(1)$ still hold, when $\|\;\cdot\;\|$ is defined in the obvious (square-root of squared sum of array components) way?

Comment: Hint: Try small cases and see,  actually I think it can be generalized.

Comment: Not sure though, but yes Seems computationally generaizable,  but how much physical interpretation it has,  I quiet wonder.

Comment: The Plancherel theorem holds for the Fourier transform in any locally compact Abelian group with Haar measure and the right normalization.  See the article on Pontryagin duality in wikipedia.  Finite Abelian groups $\Bbb{Z}/k\Bbb{Z}$ and $(\Bbb{Z}/k\Bbb{Z})^d$ with discrete topology and (scaled) counting measure are particular cases of the general setting of locally compact Abelian groups.

Comment: @JohnDoe So, you are claiming that $(1)$ still holds?

Comment: @0xbadf00d:  I don't understand your notation exactly and am not sure about the normalization factor $\frac{1}{k}$.  The group is $G=\Bbb{Z}/k_1\Bbb{Z}\times\dots\times\Bbb{Z}/k_d\Bbb{Z}$, which is its own dual.  So $x_i$ and $\omega$ must run over all elements of $G$.  If $k=k_1\cdot\dots\cdot k_d$, the normalization is probably correct because then it's a probability measure and I think on a compact group the Haar measure on both $G$ and $\hat{G}$ should be normalized to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S = \{0,\dots,k_1-1\}\times\cdots\times\{0,\dots,k_d-1\}$.  Let $x:S\rightarrow \Bbb{C}$ be some function.  Then $\hat{x}:S\rightarrow \Bbb{C}$ is defined by
$$\hat{x}(\omega) = \frac{1}{\prod_{m=1}^d \sqrt{k_m}} \sum_{\tau\in S} x(\tau)\exp\left(-2\pi i\sum_{m=1}^d \frac{\omega(m)\tau(m)}{k_m}\right)$$
The inversion formula is
$$x(\tau) = \frac{1}{\prod_{m=1}^d \sqrt{k_m}} \sum_{\omega\in S} \hat{x}(\omega)\exp\left(2\pi i\sum_{m=1}^d \frac{\omega(m)\tau(m)}{k_m}\right)$$
and with this normalization
$$\|x\|_2 = \|\hat{x}\|_2$$
where
$$\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{\tau\in S} |x(\tau)|^2}$$
and similarly for $\|\hat{x}\|_2$.